# Generate array of object with property in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

https://jsfiddle.net/x991kcus/

I'm able to generate dates array given a start date and end date as params, but what I want is actually array of object like this

```
[{date:"2017-4-01"},{{date:"2017-4-02"}}]
```

Below code gave me array.

```
function generateDates(startDate, stopDate) {
  var dateArray = [];
  var currentDate = moment(startDate);
  var stopDate = moment(stopDate);
  while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
    dateArray.push(moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
    currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
  }

  return dateArray;
}
```

Comment: Before `push`ing to the array, create an object `o` and assign the date to `o.date`. Then push the `o` to the array.

Comment: change  dateArray.push({date : moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') }) like this https://jsfiddle.net/x991kcus/2/

Comment: You should use `date.isAfter(date2)` instead of `<=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could push an object with the generated date.

```
dateArray.push({ date: moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') });
//             ^^^^^^^                                          ^ wrap in object
```

```js
const start_date_of_month = moment().format("YYYY-MM-01"),
      end_date_of_month = moment().format("YYYY-MM-") + moment().daysInMonth();

function generateDates(startDate, stopDate) {
    var dateArray = [],
        currentDate = moment(startDate),
        stopDate = moment(stopDate);

    while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
        dateArray.push({ date: moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') });
        currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
    }
    return dateArray;
}

console.log(generateDates(start_date_of_month, end_date_of_month));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can push an object to the dateArray

```
function generateDates(startDate, stopDate) {
  var dateArray = [];
  var currentDate = moment(startDate);
  var stopDate = moment(stopDate);
  while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
    obj = {};
    obj.date = moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')};
    dateArray.push(obj)
    currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
  }
  return dateArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/x991kcus/4/

```
while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
    var dateObject = {};
    dateObject.date = moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    dateArray.push(dateObject);
    currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using a Object Constructor in JavaScript is a standard way to create an "object type"

```
function dateObject(date) {
    this.date= date;
}

function generateDates(startDate, stopDate) {
  var dateArray = [];
  var currentDate = moment(startDate);
  var stopDate = moment(stopDate);
  while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
    dateArray.push(new dateObject(moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')))
    currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
  }

  return dateArray;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/x991kcus/6/)